# Refer good books for the following topics in Image processing

Tags: image-processing

Thanks for reading my question. Please refer good books(links, if possible) for the following topics in Image processing. Your help is very much appreciated.

*UNIT II SEGMENTATION*

**Fuzzy clustering, Watershed algorithm, Active contour methods, Texture feature based segmentation, Model based segmentation, Atlas based segmentation, Wavelet based Segmentation methods.**

*UNIT III FEATURE EXTRACTION*

**Texture descriptors- Autocorrelation, Co-occurrence features, Runlength features, Fractal model based features, Gabor filter, wavelet features.**

*UNIT IV REGISTRATION AND IMAGE FUSION*

**Image Fusion-Overview of image fusion, pixel fusion, Multiresolution based fusion discrete wavelet transform, Curvelet transform. Region based fusion.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Multiresolution based fusion discrete wavelet transform you may refer the following
" A Wavelet based image fusion tutorial " by Gonzalo Pajares ( available at: www.ELSEVIERcomputer science.com)

"Wavelet based image fusion techniques - An introduction ,review and comparison by Krista Amolins

for Curvelet transform refer " Wavelet for image fusion" by shih-Gu Huang

Comment: What about Unit 2?

Answer (score 0):

For first two:

Feature Extraction & Image Processing for Computer Vision, by Mark Nixon and Alberto S Aguado
Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications (Texts in Computer Science) by Richard Szeliski

For last one

Sparse Image and Signal Processing Wavelets, Curvelets, Morphological Diversity

AUTHORS:
Jean-Luc Starck, Centre d'Etudes de Saclay, FranceFionn Murtagh, Royal Holloway, University of LondonJalal M. Fadili, Ecole Nationale Supérieure d'Ingénieurs de Caen, France

Comment: The links respectively:

http://www.amazon.com/Feature-Extraction-Processing-Computer-Vision/dp/0123965497/ref=sr_1_7?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1388493820&sr=1-7&keywords=computer+vision

http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Vision-Algorithms-Applications-Science/dp/1848829345/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1388493820&sr=1-2&keywords=computer+vision

http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/computer-science/computer-graphics-image-processing-and-robotics/sparse-image-and-signal-processing-wavelets-curvelets-morphological-diversity

Comment: Here is a must-have book for a probabilistic point of view:

http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Vision-Models-Learning-Inference/dp/1107011795/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_z

Comment: Model based segmentation, Atlas based segmentation, Wavelet based Segmentation methods are not available in Feature Extraction & Image Processing for Computer Vision, by Mark Nixon and Alberto S Aguado

Comment: Exactly. That's why I only recommend it for feature extraction.